# How Did Neural Networks Overcome the Bias/Variance Dilemma?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Deep learning has been seen as a [rebranding of Neural Networks](http://fastml.com/michael-jordan-on-deep-learning/).

Were the issues presented in the paper  ["Neural Networks and the Bias/Variance Dilemma" by Stuart Geman](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/geman/Homepage/Essays%20and%20ideas%20about%20neurobiology/bias-variance.pdf) ever resolved in the architectures in use today?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We learned a lot about NN, in particular:

- we now learn better **representations** due to progress in unsupervised/autoregressive learning, such as restricted boltzman machines, autoencoders, denoising autoencoders, variational autoencoders, which help as stabilize the process, learn from reasonable representations
- we have better priors - not neceserly in the strict probabilistic sense, but we know, that for example in image processing a good architecture is the convolutional one, thus we have a smaller (in terms of parameters), but better suited for the problem - models. Consequently we are less prone to overfitting.
- we have better optimization techniques and activation functions - which help us with underfitting (we can learn larger networks), in particular - we can learn deeper networks. Why is deep often better then wide? Because again - this is another prior, the assumption that representation should be hierarchical, and it seems to be valid prior for many modern problems (even that not all of them).
- dropout, and other techniques brought as better regularization methods (than previously known and used simple weights priors) - which again limits problem with overfitting (variance).

There are many more things that changed, but in general - we were simply able to find better architectures, better assumptions, thus we now search in more narrow class of hypotheses. Consequently - we overfit less (variance), and underfit less (bias) - yet there is still lots to be done!

Next thing is, as @david pointed out, amount of data. We have huge datasets now, we often have access to more data that we can process in a reasonable time, and obviously more data means less variance - even highly overfitting models start to behave well.

Last, but not least - hardware. This is something that every single deep learning expert will tell you - our computers got stronger. We still use the same algorithms, the same architectures (with many little tweaks, but the core is the same), but our hardware is exponentially faster, and this changes **a lot**.

Comment: Plus one, good overview. Afaik, after all the early 2000's deep learning stuff, current state-of-the-art is just using a "normal" feed-forward network, a suitable activation (e.g. maxout) and a slightly changed training procedure (dropout -- reducing variance similar to random forests). Do you agree?

Comment: convnets are massively used, which is a very strong prior (very specific architecture). Similarly - in rnn, discovery of lstm changes a lot (as we no longer have a problem with vanishing/exploding gradient, or at least not too much). Thus I would not say that we use "normal" nn. The "normal" ones, given suitable training and activation became much deeper and narrower then previously - and this also changed a lot (as previously we were unable to fit those and instaed used shallow but wide architectuers). This is not "that" different. But all these small changes change a lot at the end :-)

Comment: Agreed, new or normal depends on the point of view ;-) I see two reasons for convnets: historical (strong) and prior-knowledge (weak, and probably artificial). What do you think is their future status? Are they dying out or will they remain? Afaik, recent challenges were often won by more-or-less standard deep nets (i.e. without much human structuring).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers guys! Learning representations from architectures, in general, is fascinating (unsupervised, supervised, and via rl). And leveraging pre-trained architecture's representations with transfer-learning for those datasets with much less samples. I was trying to convince myself that the modular architecture was designed rather than "hacked".

Answer (score 1):

@lejlot gave a good overview. I want to point to two specific parts of the whole process.

First, neural networks are universal approximators. That means, their bias in principle can be made arbitrarily small. The problem that was rather thought to be severe was overfitting -- too large variance.

Now, a common and successful way in Machine Learning to deal with too large variance is by "averaging it away" over many different predictions -- which should be as uncorrelated as possible. This worked in Random Forests, for instance, and in this way I tend to understand current Neural Networks as well (particular the maxout+dropout stuff). Of course, this is a narrow view -- there is further this whole representational learning stuff, the not explaining-away property, etc. -- but it's one I find suitable for your question regarding the bias/variance tradeoff.

Second point: there is no better way to prevent overfitting than having very much data. And currently we're in the situation to gather a lot of data.